# Calling a PHP script using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hi i am calling a php file using ajax after an interval of time. In my php file i simply echo a text line. But it didnt show me any output after time interval..

here is my ajax code form where i am calling my php file..

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',    
        type: 'post',    
        data: {"token": "your_token"}, });   
    }, 5000);
});

</script>
```

code inside the process.php file

```
<?php

echo "hello testing";

?>
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the response. You need a `success` callback.

Comment: From where are you calling? For example in chrome you cannot Ajax to a web server from an HTML file loaded from file system. (And you need a callback ;))

Comment: With Jquery ajax, there is a specific parameter, which is used to capture the data echoed at the server side(php script), i.e., `success:`. like this `$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});`  **ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol how to add a success callback? can u please explain??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User the success and error function of ajax. for eg

```
    $.ajax ({
    url: 'process.php',
    type:'post'
    data:data1,

    success: function (response) {
    //alert response here you will get the value hello testing
    alert (response);
    },

error {
alert ('error');
}

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't handling the response from php script. You need to get it by `success` parameter in ajax. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'process.php',    
      type: 'post',    
      data: 'x=1&y=2', // data here! use query strings like this or;
   // data: { x: '1', y: '2' }
      success: function(response) { alert(response); } // alert the response text
                                    // returns 'hello testing'
      error: function(){ alert('error while posting data'); }
    }); 
}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: i want to execute a function in php file to add data into the database. will it be done without using success??

Comment: yes it will. Success is only to handle response from file. If you get success response(200 http code) you can be 100% sure that request has been sent to php file.

Comment: Can i send a variable value using query string in the porcess.php file for example process.php?x=1&y=2

Comment: Yea, Robert is right. You can also add error parameter to your ajax function, which will indicate if there's errors in request. See my edit. Yes, you can send variables by ajax by attaching the contents to `data` parameter. I made an example please check it.

Comment: `success`, `error` and `complete` callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery's version 1.8. Please use `done`, `fail` and `always` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code to use the response.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',    
        type: 'post',    
        data: {"token": "your_token"},
     success:function(str){
 $("#YOUR_ELEMENT").html(str);
}
 });   

}, 5000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Just change your JQuery script to show the response after successful request it can be done with done() or success functions.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',    
        type: 'post',    
        data: { token: "your_token"}}).done(function(msg){
              $("#response").append(msg);
        }; 
    }, 5000);
});
```

This will append reponses to #response every 5s when ajax request is successful.

Answer (score 0):

the success block, which handles the data returned from remote script is present in your code. you may need to add something like this .

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',    
    type: 'post',    
    data: {"token": "your_token"}, 
    }).done(function( data) {
               //data received from remote script 
           });   
  }, 5000);
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Timeout is not the culprit here.

- We need to make sure that you have a server where `process.php` resides and its running fine.
- Make sure the path for the file `process.php` is right. You can use browser's developer tools. When the request is made you will see a new entry under "Network" tab of the developer tools. Exploring it you can get the url at which it the file should be available.

I would suggest using Google Chrome's "postman" extension to test the ajax call before implementing it in your code.

Also you need to have a callback that will run in case of request success or failure. Once you get the string in success response, you can do whatever you intend to do with it.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',    
                type: 'post',    
                data: {"token": "your_token"} //removed the comma from last argument
            }).done(function(serverResponse) {
                alert( "Success: " + serverResponse ); //Will show success alert with concatenated text string if the request is successful
            }).fail(function(serverResponse) {
                alert( "Error: " + serverResponse.message); //Will show error alert with concatenated error message
            });
        }, 5000);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

the php page sends the string "hello testing", and you have to manage it.

take a look here for an example: [click me](http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html)